Can't install DBD::mysql on Windows Strawberry Perl
I run Strawberry Perl 5.38.2 on Windows 11 and MySQL 8.0.37. When I try to install DBD::mysql and run make test, it produces dubious on most of the tests like shown in the code. Also, the very last subtest keeps running without output
Additional note: Strawberry Perl release note mentioned "TODO: libmysql needs updates before DBD::mysql can be built." but i do not know how to do it
cpan> look for DBD::mysql
Database was generated on Wed, 26 Jun 2024 17:37:09 GMT
Warning: Cannot look for, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /for/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
Running look for module 'DBD::mysql'

Trying to open a subshell in the build directory...
Checksum for D:\apps\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\D\DV\DVEEDEN\DBD-mysql-5.006.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache D:\apps\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Working directory is D:\apps\strawberry\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-5.006-2
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\apps\strawberry\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-5.006-2>perl MakeFile.PL


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the
database user '' can connect to your MySQL server
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others.

mysql> CREATE USER ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 's3kr1t';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO ''@'localhost';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -ID:/apps/MySQL/MySQLServer/include
  ldflags       (mysql_config) =
  libs          (mysql_config) = -LD:/apps/MySQL/MySQLServer/lib -lmysql
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) =
  testpassword  (default     ) =
  testport      (default     ) =
  testsocket    (default     ) =
  testuser      (guessed     ) =
  version       (mysql_config) = 8.0.37

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Looks good.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Using DBI 1.643 (for perl 5.038002 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread) installed in D:/apps/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBI/
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
"\x{0159}" does not map to cp437 at D:/apps/strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 1271.
"\x{0159}" does not map to cp437 at D:/apps/strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 1271.
"\x{0159}" does not map to cp437 at D:/apps/strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 1271.
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

D:\apps\strawberry\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-5.006-2>make test
"D:\apps\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- mysql.bs blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.bs 644
"D:\apps\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00base.t .............................. 1/6 # Driver version is 5.006
t/00base.t .............................. ok
t/01caching_sha2_prime.t ................ Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/05dbcreate.t .......................... Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/10connect.t ........................... Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/15reconnect.t ......................... Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/16dbi-get_info.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/17quote.t ............................. Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/20createdrop.t ........................ Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/25lockunlock.t ........................ Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/29warnings.t .......................... Dubious, test returned 116 (wstat 29696, 0x7400)
No subtests run
t/30insertfetch.t .......................

i want to perfectly install DBD::MySQL but the error keeps happening

Note that there is no look for command in the CPAN.pm shell. It's just look MODULE.

The instructions the OP needs are in the error message.

StrawberryPerl already comes with DBD::mysql. Why are you trying to reinstall it?

These module tests want to connect to a database and needs credentials that you did not supply. Note the error message tells you what to do.
However, you can skip the tests, which his sometimes reasonable for very-highly scrutinized modules such as DBD::mysql:
cpan -T DBD::mysql

or
cpanm --notest DBD::mysql


As per https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/405

Use DBD::mysql v4. I intent to keep v4 around for situations like
this. Just don't expect any major changes/improvements in v4.
Compile DBD::mysql against MySQL 8.x client libraries and keep using
MySQL 5.7 as server.
Use DBD::mysql as provided by your OS.

I have used below mentioned command to install DBD::mysql version 4.052 (Windows OS ,Strawberry Perl)
cpanm --notest DBD::mysql@4.052

Output
! Finding DBD::mysql (== 4.052) on cpanmetadb failed.
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.052.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.052 ... OK
Building DBD-mysql-4.052 ... OK
Successfully installed DBD-mysql-4.052
1 distribution installed

Note : Strawberry Perl has cpanm by default.

I think there’s an error in this line:

mysql> CREATE USER ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 's3kr1t';

I think the answer is provided above too:

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:
perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I’m not sure what the right username should be, but the current blank (empty string) seems wrong.

It does not work, the problem appears again
